# Rollback sequence

Tags: oracle10g, sequence

I have a table where the primary key is populated using a sequence. Current version:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE xxxx.SEQ_xyz
START WITH 135
MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
MINVALUE 1
NOCYCLE
NOCACHE
ORDER;
```

There is an application which deletes some rows from a table. When this happens, I want to get the next available number instead of what sequence shows. Say I insert:
     136 x
     137 y
     138 z

so the sequence is now at 139. if i delete 136, 137, 138, I want sequence to go back to 136 instead of staying at 139. Is this possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you only delete 136 & 137, but 138 still exists? What if you delete 136, 137, 138 and another process has inserted 140, but not commited, so you can't see that 140 exists?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is, write a before delete on each row trigger which would replace the sequence with "start with" the entry which is going to be deleted. But this will create lot of problems as mentioned by Shannon Severance. 
e.g 136 gets deleted, the trigger replaces the old sequence, now the sequence starts with 136. you will be able to insert something with primary key as 136 but the next time you'll try to insert data in the table you won't be able to insert it as it will violate the primary key constraint (137, 138 would be there in the table)

I don't see any reason why you what to go back to the previously deleted no. in your sequence. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It will cause more harm then good so I will keep it as it is. Thanks